# Way to group rows in a table based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to find out if there is a way to group rows in a table within a database based on the values from multiple columns. My specific problem is that I am trying to form groups of people based on multiple different criteria that would be entered by students such as predefined choices for hobbies, a set time availability range, and a set GPA range. Currently I am working in Microsoft Access. Ideally the priority would be the choices for hobbies, time availability, and the GPA. I had tried to organize the data using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Student ORDER BY Interest, TimeAvailable, GPA
```

I then realized that my logic behind the organization was wrong because I realized I was using the ORDER BY incorrectly. I wanted the subsequent criteria to then get ordered all over again if there weren't matches from the first one. I guess I had a brain fart haha. I was planning on iteratively looping through the data selecting the top 3 rows each time using the following:

```
    Declare @Counter = Int
    Set @Counter = 1
    
    While Student.GroupID = null
    
    Begin
    Declare @I = Int
    Set I = 1
    
    WHILE I <=3

(Something that would set the GroupID to @Counter)
```

Sample Data:

| Email | FirstName | GroupID | Interest | TimeAvailability | GPA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tomb | Tom | null | Hiking | 1-10 hours | 3.0 |
| Bjon | Bob | null | Reading | 11-20 hours | 2.5 |
| Rburn | Rex | null | Hiking | 1-10 hours | 3.0 |
| Gched | Grace | null | Sports | 11-20 hours | 3.0 |
| EPhil | Eren | null | Hiking | 1-10 hours | 2.0 |
| Gnen | George | null | Sports | 11-20 hours | 2.5 |
| PBull | Pedro | null | Hiking | 11-20 hours | 2.5 |
| FredF | Fred | null | Reading | 1-10 hours | 2.0 |
| RegM | Reggie | null | Reading | 11-20 hours | 2.0 |

Desired Output:

| Email | FirstName | GroupID | Interest | TimeAvailability | GPA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tomb | Tom | 1 | Hiking | 1-10 hours | 3.0 |
| Rburn | Rex | 1 | Hiking | 1-10 hours | 3.0 |
| EPhil | Eren | 1 | Hiking | 1-10 hours | 2.0 |
| Bjon | Bob | 2 | Reading | 11-20 hours | 2.5 |
| FredF | Fred | 2 | Reading | 1-10 hours | 2.0 |
| RegM | Reggie | 2 | Reading | 11-20 hours | 2.0 |
| Gched | Grace | 3 | Sports | 11-20 hours | 3.0 |
| Gnen | George | 3 | Sports | 11-20 hours | 2.5 |
| PBull | Pedro | 3 | Hiking | 11-20 hours | 2.5 |

To clarify, my goal would be to sort the data into groups of a specified integer (I had been using 3, but it could be more or less) based on the interest first and if there wasn't a match, it would go to the TimeAvailable, and if not a match, it would just keep going to GPA. In the above desired output, The interests are alike for the first two groups so that's why they were matched. Since there was one left over for the Hiking interest, PBull was grouped with Gched and Gnen due to TimeAvailability matching.

Any help is greatly appreciated. If there are better suggestions for trying to accomplish this please let me know!

Comment: Some sample data would sure help out here...

Comment: I have added some sample data. Thank you to @Tim Williams for helping to edit to to look better

Comment: Sample of desired output would be nice as well. I am not understanding your narrative. Not a complete match to what? Multiple interest fields is not a normalized structure.

Comment: @June7 I'm sorry for being unclear. I will get rid of having multiple interest fields then. By doing that I actually feel closer to what I am trying to achieve. I will add in the desired output and edit the dataset given. Thanks! This whole problem was an open ended project and I assumed I was doing it in the best way, but I don't really have too much experience with this part which is why I came here for help after my methods weren't working.

Comment: Do you know how to use GROUP BY?

Comment: @WalterMitty yes, but I don't think GROUP BY does what I am trying to do. Isn't it just used when data is aggregated? If I use an aggregate function for this, sure I can see how many people have a particular interest or GPA or availability, but I don't think that is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: And what would keep tomb from being the 'left over' Hiking record and get thrown into another group? Is there a unique identifier field, such as an autonumber? I very much doubt this can be accomplished with SQL alone and will require VBA - very complicated VBA.

Comment: @June7 I was thinking that tomb would be selected into that group first since the data had an ORDER BY applied to it and that record was the first one after that initial sort. Thank you for the tip though, maybe I need to try alternative methods for this problem to forming groups based on Interest, Availability, and GPA

Comment: I think you mostly need to clearly state the problem and the desired solution.

Comment: Have you considered using GROUP BY to define the groups you want, and then joining the result with the original tables in order to associate each record with a group?  I'm sorry if this is unclear,  but your statement of the goal was unclear.